# Automating date of a column in Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fully automate a keyword report on Google Sheet.
I export my data on a monthly basis from an API called Supermetrics.
My script below add a new column (after F) an copy the data to the newly created column (Only the 'date' part of the script isn't working).
I'd like the header of this column to be the date of my data export.

1. How can I name my column by the date I want (which is contains in cell C18)?
2. How can I edit my script so that my column has the name of a particular date (let say 1st of each month)?

Below the link to my Google sheet and the script. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZD-3r3sceK0H7Q17agyZqVggH3D6utnEFPy69aP2wUg/edit#gid=0

```
function insertColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('KW');
  var date = new Date();
  var valuestocopy = sheet.getRange(2, 6, 14, 1)
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(6).getRange(1,15).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("DD.MM.YY");
  valuestocopy.copyValuesToRange(sheet, 7, 7, 2, 15);
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Does your first question refer to how to set the header of column by formula rather than a script? And as for your second question - currently the script sets the header of the new column to the date of today. What would you like instead? Set the date to the 1rst of the CURRENT month?

Comment: @ziganotschka Hi, thanks for your answer.
For the first question, I have a date setup in cell C18 (which will be changing on a monthly basis). Instead of using "var date = new Date();" that gives you the date of today, I would like my script to use the date that I have in cell C18.

The second question has already been answered by another nice soul :)

Comment: Thanks for coming back @Damien! Since one of the quesitons has already been answered, I recommend you to post the other one as a new post - to avoid confusion and follow the Stackoverflow guidelines of asking one quesiton per post.

Comment: @ziganotschka Alright sure! Sorry I'm not really familiar with the guidelines of this forum yet, I've just registered. I will do that, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your code didn't work because of your usage of the getRange() function in line 6. What your code did was to point at the cell in row 1 column 15 and to insert the date in this cell. So what I did was to point the function to the desired cell (G1).

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('KW');
  var date = new Date();
  var valuestocopy = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(6).getRange("G1").setValue(date).setNumberFormat("DD/MM/YY");
  valuestocopy.copyValuesToRange(sheet, 7, 7, 2, sheet.getLastRow());
  sheet.getRange(1,6,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();
}
```

With this code, the timestamp is already generated from the script and pasted on row 1 of the newly inserted column instead of copying the data stored in cell C18 which contains the current timestamp as well.

Sheet before the application of the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEBat.png

Sheet after the application of the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgzup.png

Reference: [copyValuesToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend) [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangea1notation) [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getLastRow())

Edit: I added the sheet.getLastRow() option during range selection so that it can adjust based on the data that needs to be copied.

Comment: Hi PatrickdC,

Thanks a lot for your answer, it's working now thanks to you, that's great !
Indeed G1 was the cell I was supposed to point my function to.

Also, I did not know the function getlastrow(), it's very convenient, I will definitely use it again!

Just one more question: Do you know what can I add to my entire script to make it run on the first day of each month (morning time if possible) automatically without any human interaction?

Comment: (Sorry if I'm not answering properly, I'm new in this forum and I need to get used to the user interface)

Comment: Hello Damien, you can actually add an installable trigger which is time-driven. To create the trigger, you can go to the left side panel of the Apps Script and select Triggers (the one with the clock icon). Then, you can click on the "+ Add Trigger" button. You can then choose which function to run. On the select event source, select "time-driven". Under type of time based trigger, select "Month timer". Under day of the month, select "1st". Please refer to this link for more details: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en